# How can I convert a NSString that contains timezone info to NSDate?

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I am receiving JSON data from a web service where the dates are in string format and includes the timezone format as you can see below:

```
{
        currencyName = EUR;
        itemID = 101064027138011;
        price = "6.95";
        priceIncTAX = 1;
        validFromDate = "2016-11-03T00:00:00";
        validToDate = "2020-01-01T00:00:00";
}
```

When I try convert the string that contains timezone into NSDate the return value is always nil/null, if I manually send in a string without the timezone info i,e @"2016-11-03" then the conversion works fine BUT the resulting date includes timezone offset etc and does not adhere to my dateFormatter

I use the following code to show the challenge at hand

```
NSString *validTo = @"2016-11-03";
NSString *validFrom = @"2020-11-03T00:00:00";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
NSDate *validToDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:validTo];
NSDate *validFromDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:validFrom];

if([NWTillHelper isDebug] == 1) {
    NSLog(@"WebServices:fetchPriceList:validToDate: >>>> %@ <<<<", validToDate);
    NSLog(@"WebServices:fetchPriceList:validFromDate: %@", validFromDate);
}
```

The debugs tell me that the string without tz info works fine (apart from not adhering to my dateFormatter) but the string with tz info does not.

How can I convert a string that contains tz info to NSDate and why is it not adhering to my dateFormatter when I send in a string without timezone information.

```
016-11-27 12:09:22.194 NWMobileTill[4275:235671] WebServices:fetchPriceList:validToDate: >>>> 2016-11-02 16:00:00 +0000 <<<<
2016-11-27 12:09:22.194 NWMobileTill[4275:235671] WebServices:fetchPriceList:validFromDate: (null)
```

Comment: There's no timezone info in your JSON date strings.

Comment: Do you really think that the format `YYYY-MM-dd` actually matches the string `2020-11-03T00:00:00`? They need to match. And don't use `YYYY`, use `yyyy` for the year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your date formatter from this

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
```

To this

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
```

As your format is different which you are getting from server and in your code you are using different date format

**Edit**

As @rmaddy mentioned in his comment you are not getting timezone in your date string which you are getting from your server and date formatter will convert you string to date as per the user's current time zone.

As a suggestion I would like to mention to you that your date string must contain timezone as well something like this

> 2016-11-27T10:39:57-05:30

This string contains IST timezone and with your date formatter which is

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];
```

You will get the date as per the timezone of your date string not as per user's locale.

Comment: Yes Rajat is right. You need to change format to yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss

Comment: The fact that there is no timezone info in the date string (that's bad) brings up another issue. What timezone should be used to parse these date strings? By default these will be treated as dates in the user's locale time which is unlikely to be correct since they are coming from some server.

Comment: Yes, I am completely agree with you @rmaddy , there is no timezone in the strings and it will be converted as per user's local timezone

Comment: I might have misunderstood the use of the dateFormatter, I thought I could convert from string and also change the date format at the same time from for example yyyy-MM-dd to yy--MM-dd or whatever I need? are you saying in the conversion I need them to match exactly for the conversion to work but then I apply another dateFormatter to change the actual format to what I need?

Comment: Yes if you want to change the date as per your requirement then you have to change the dateformatter format, after getting the date, change your dateformat as per your requirement